# Finding Confidence Interval for Lower Bounded Truncated Normal Distribution

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval, truncated-normal-distribution, truncated-distributions

I am working on finding a confidence interval for data that follows a lower bounded truncated normal distribution (lbtnd) bounded from 0 to $\infty$. I am having difficulty completely understanding how to go about this.

What I am getting so far is I take the mean ($m$) and variance ($v$) of the data and then find the truncated mean ($m_t$) and truncated variance ($v_t$) using these calculations (Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution)):

> [image: Mean and Variance Calculations for lbtnd. Source: Wikipedia]

Then, I am not sure if we get the 95% Confidence Interval lower bound by $(m_t - 1.96\sqrt{v_t/n})$ and the upper bound by $(m_t + 1.96\sqrt{v_t/n})$?

Or, if the lower bound uses the truncated parameters $($i.e. $(m_t - 1.96\sqrt{v_t/n}))$ and the upper bound uses the non-truncated parameter $($i.e. $(m - 1.96\sqrt{v/n}))$ since it is only lower bounded?

Ultimately I would like to understand how to calculate the confidence interval for a lower bounded truncated normal distribution and how it is different from the calculations from the 95% confidence interval for the normal distribution. My objective is to find a window where the mean would fall commonly for a truncated normal distribution.

Any help and as much detail is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the target of your confidence interval?  Are you trying to estimate $\mu$ or the mean of the distribution?  And since confidence intervals are *statistics*--they are functions of the *data*--could you explain what you mean by "uses the truncated parameters"?

Comment: Thank you for the questions @whuber. The target is to recognize any unusual data points, such as when a point falls outside the two standard deviations from the mean of the normal distribution. I meant "uses the truncated parameter" as in the way we calculate the confidence interval for a normal distribution do we use the truncated mean and truncated variance in place of the non-truncated versions of these parameters.

Comment: "Recognize unusual data points" is not *ever* done by computing confidence intervals.  Please edit your post so that it asks the question you need answered!